# Batch Builds in Visual Studio 6 for VC++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, batch-build

In VS 2008 and VS 2010, one can easily create a solution and modify the "Solution Configuration". We can choose what configuration each project gets built in when we trigger a build at the solution level.

Is such a facility available in the Visual Studio 6.0?

In my experience:
when a configuration is chosen (form the list available) in VS6 for a VC++ project, the dependencies (which themselves have multiple configurations defined) get built in some random order. There is no way to control the configurations of dependencies at build time.

"Batch Build" does come close to this but is not as flexible for my purpose.

I have tried various options in the VS6. 
Hope I am clear.

Comment: If you must continue to use VS6 for some project, you could still upgrade your MAKE tools and not rely on VS for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link on the MSDEV command line.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699274(v=vs.60).aspx

There *is* a way to control the building of dependencies.  Specify `/NORECURSE` and dependencies will not be built.

I use `/REBUILD` with `/NORECURSE` to keep the dependencies from getting built.

And I build each project one at a time inside the workspace in a bat file by doing a chdir to the subdirectory and calling MSDEV just for that subproject:

```
msdev myproject.dsp /MAKE "myproject - Win32 Debug" /REBUILD /NORECURSE > Build.log
```

Then I `cd` to the next project directory one at a time.

On a side note, I had difficulties for several years where `NMAKE` would not work for my specific tasks.  Turns out that the `PATH` environment variable inside MSDEV (Visual Studio 6.0) is *different* from the `PATH` environment variable of a command shell you would run `NMAKE` on.

The Path used by the `MSDEV` shell is the `%PATH%` at the time Visual Studio 6 was installed.  We use this and poke the registry as needed for `MSDEV` to get the correct path setup when switching revisions of our software; however this doesn't help update the `%PATH%`.  The `MSDEV` path can be queried with a query script.  I don't have my example handy.

That is why builds in `MSDEV` sometimes work when builds using the command line don't, as the path to DLLs differ, and any custom build steps that run .exe will not work outside of the MSDEV environment unless the path is updated.

I have a script somewhere that reads the queries the registry to extract the MSDEV path and update PATH of a shell so that batch scripts doing nmake will work as they would inside the MSDEV shell environment. The problem with the REGISTRY QUERY is that the return arguments differ with different flavors of Windows (XP/SERVER2003/...).

One thing I just discovered is that [Incredibuild](https://www.incredibuild.com/) works with the old VS6.0 MSDEV IDE.  This is a game changer.  It distributes builds.  I'm evaluating it now, but it might be useful to anyone waiting for long VS6.0 builds.